# How to install cleanlab library in AWS sagemaker?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use the `find_label_issues` function from [cleanlab](https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab?tab=readme-ov-file) library in AWS SageMaker.

After conducting some research, I came across this notebook: https://github.com/cleanlab/aws-marketplace/blob/main/label-inspector/label_inspector.ipynb, as well as this AWS Marketplace page: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-en3c45ncm5som. Both seem to suggest using Cleanlab through AWS Marketplace. I am wondering if there's a more straightforward way to use the `find_label_issues` function directly in SageMaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install clean lab via Pip install - https://docs.cleanlab.ai/stable/index.html. If using training jobs you should be able to add this to requirements.txt and SageMaker will install it.